# is constructor depend on 'new' keyword to initialize the instance variable

Tags: java, oop, memory-management

```
class Abs
{
int x;
public static void main(String []args)
{
 // i'm not using 'new' keyword here 
}

}
```

after compile, will instance variable 'x' initialize with its default value ? if 'new' keyword is used to allocate memory in heap then how 'x' gate memory ... if NO it means constructor is depend on 'new' keyword to initialize instance variable ?

Comment: x is not defined yet. It will be when you create a new object using `new Abs()`

Comment: `public static void main` is not a constructor, nor can you access `Abs#x` from within it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misunderstood the concept of new keyword and constructor.

Check whether it is useful for you new keyword is used to create new memory block in which we can store all the variables and methods in that using constructor. In that all variables will store in a stack and methods will store in heap.

For Example: `NewClass obj = new NewClass();`
in this code new keyword will create a fresh memory block for the type of class which mentioned after the keyword and the constructor will add all variables and methods to that memory. That memory has some address to refer that address obj is used as a name of that address, so that we can call all the assets of that class using object name. And hope you know that we can create 'n' no of objects for a single class and every object will have a separate block of memory.

Coming to your question, In this code x will not be defined until you create an instance like this `new Abs();`.